# maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to use Bing maps in an app, needs to be Bing as will be used in China. I get
error messages, What has caused this???? :
:app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.microsoft.maps:maps-sdk:1.3.0.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://microsoftmaps.jfrog.io/artifactory/Maven/com/microsoft/maps/maps-sdk/1.3.0/maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.microsoft.maps:maps-sdk:1.3.0.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://microsoftmaps.jfrog.io/artifactory/Maven/com/microsoft/maps/maps-sdk/1.3.0/maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.microsoft.maps:maps-sdk:1.3.0.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://microsoftmaps.jfrog.io/artifactory/Maven/com/microsoft/maps/maps-sdk/1.3.0/maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.microsoft.maps:maps-sdk:1.3.0.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://microsoftmaps.jfrog.io/artifactory/Maven/com/microsoft/maps/maps-sdk/1.3.0/maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.microsoft.maps:maps-sdk:1.3.0.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://microsoftmaps.jfrog.io/artifactory/Maven/com/microsoft/maps/maps-sdk/1.3.0/maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.microsoft.maps:maps-sdk:1.3.0.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://microsoftmaps.jfrog.io/artifactory/Maven/com/microsoft/maps/maps-sdk/1.3.0/maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.microsoft.maps:maps-sdk:1.3.0.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://microsoftmaps.jfrog.io/artifactory/Maven/com/microsoft/maps/maps-sdk/1.3.0/maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.microsoft.maps:maps-sdk:1.3.0.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://microsoftmaps.jfrog.io/artifactory/Maven/com/microsoft/maps/maps-sdk/1.3.0/maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
org.gradle.internal.execution.fingerprint.InputFingerprinter$InputFileFingerprintingException: Cannot fingerprint input file property 'externalLibNativeLibs': Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.microsoft.maps:maps-sdk:1.3.0.
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://microsoftmaps.jfrog.io/artifactory/Maven/com/microsoft/maps/maps-sdk/1.3.0/maps-sdk-1.3.0.pom
Already seen doctype

Tried to find solution but does not seem to be one online. What has caused this???

Comment: well, `Your server is no longer active` is what jfrog says about it